# Openfaces, ajax and IE7

Tags: jsf-2, openfaces

I am using a combination of tabbedPane and dataTable for a section on a screen. I use loadingMode="ajaxLazy" so that the data is only retrieved when it is needed. The xhtml is listed below.

Main.xhtml

```
<o:tabbedPane selectionChangeListener="#{aListener.selectionChanged}" loadingMode="ajaxLazy"> 
     ... 
     <o:subPanel caption="Pane X"> 
           <ui:include src="tableContainingFragment.xhtml" /> 
     </o:subPanel> 
     ...
</o:tabbedPane>
```

tableContainingFragment.xhtml

```
<o:dataTable value="#{sourceBean.rows}" var="row"> 
     ... 
</o:dataTable>
```

The implementation works in Chrome, Firefox and IE8, but not in IE7. The ajax call to the service is executed and the required data retrieved, but the tab is never rendered. The tabbedPane component stays on the tab that was initially on page load. There are other tabs that does not require an ajax call to get the data and they do render when selected.

We are using Openface 3.0.

Does anybody know how to get it to work in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

Openfaces 3.x-nightly builds do not seem to have the problem

Comment: I am however finding some other problems with IE7 and OpenFaces 3.x-nightly builds, including performance issues.